# Restart Java-Application from the inside (without searching the current path and execute it)

Tags: java, stack

I have code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    Application.start();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }catch (Exception i){}
    main(args);
  }
}
```

If the program fails, `main` will be called again in the "catch"-section. This is really ugly I know.

My biggest problem is the fact, that each call of `main` will generate a new instance on the stack, which prevents the old instance to get inactive (and garbage collected).

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:
The goal is, that if the application gets an error while it is running, it should COMPLETELY restart. The error can appear when the program is running, not before it starts to run.

The RAM takes more and more space, the more main() is newly called (=the more exceptions appear).

Application.start() should only be called, if there appears an exception.
I tried to visualize it with a cheapy paint drawing. :)

[image]

Comment: How do know that application has been stated successfully?

Comment: Is there an objection to using an external watcher program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree you should avoid recursion here. Why not just move the Thread.sleep out of the catch block and use a boolean flag that is only set to true if things work OK.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  boolean ok = false;
  while (!ok) {
    try {
      Application.start();
      ok = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // error message
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh? If "ok" is set to "true", it will just break, instead of restart. :)

Comment: @TrudleR: exactly! And ok will only be set to true if ***no exception*** occurs. But if the exception occurs, then the while loop will re-loop.

Comment: Aha, I meant another scenario. It's possible, that the application starts and there occurs an internal error which lets the programm break. Then is should "restart". I don't search a solution for "wait until the Application is able to start". :)

Comment: @TrudleR: please clarify that last statement for us.

Comment: @TrudleR: I've seen your edit, and I stand by my answer other than removing the `Thread.sleep(...)` which does not seem necessary. Unless it is an application which uses some type of background threading such as a Swing application which does not run on the main thread. If that is the case, then other techniques would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not change main to something like: -

```
while(true) {
  try {
    Application.start();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {}
  }
}
```

Comment: This would create unlimited Applications.

Comment: In that case your question is not clear, this still follows the same logic as in your example the difference being no longer a recursive call to main each time an Exception is thrown.

Comment: 'Application.start()' must block as long as the application is running otherwise your idea that you can magically catch an Exception at some later point is completely flawed.